# Multistore Advanced Inventory

Tags: cart, multistore, inventory

I have two stores one which is going to be  wholesale store and the other a retail store

I want to create a product which allows me to set the cart minimum order quantity to 100 for the wholesale store and 1 for the retail store.

When I try to set this for the wholesale store the settings seem to replicate to the retail store. How can I set this so it does not use global inventory settings?

I want to do this so i can use the same sku for the stores which will eliminate the need to create multi skus and then manage multiple listings

I am using V 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

The minimum quantity has a global scope and can be set for all stores only. You'll need some MSI tweaking to solve the problem. MSI Product Sources Configuration extension can do the trick by enabling source-specific min and max quantities

[image]